# sed match date format Apr 25, 2013

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, pattern-matching

Can anyone help with a search & replace script (sed) to match a date Feb 24, 2009 and replace it with a white space?

```
 sed 's/ \(Jan\|Feb\|Mar\|Apr\|May\|Jun\|Aug\|Sep\|Oct\|Nov\|Dec\) [0-9][0-9], [2][0-9][0-9][0-9]$//g'
```

I am trying the above syntax on the file but output doesn't seem to match!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to remove the `$`(dollar sign):

```
sed 's/ \(Jan\|Feb\|Mar\|Apr\|May\|Jun\|Aug\|Sep\|Oct\|Nov\|Dec\) [0-9][0-9], [2][0-9][0-9][0-9]//g'
```

test with the sentence in your question:

```
kent$  echo "to match a date Feb 24, 2009 and replace it with a white space?"|sed 's/ \(Jan\|Feb\|Mar\|Apr\|May\|Jun\|Aug\|Sep\|Oct\|Nov\|Dec\) [0-9][0-9], [2][0-9][0-9][0-9]//g' 
to match a date and replace it with a white space?
```

Comment: Works great on Redhat however not on OS X.

Comment: check the other answer for Mac os. interesting is, you tagged the question with `linux`.. also I didn't change your codes much except for removing the dollar.... :)

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac even this sed doesn't work:

```
sed 's/Feb\|Mar//g'
```

Not even this:

```
sed 's/Feb|Mar//g'
```

However when I use extended regex switch `-E`, things start working like this:

```
sed -E 's/ (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9][0-9], [2][0-9][0-9][0-9]//g'
```

On Linux you can use `-r` flag in place of `-E`:

```
sed -r 's/ (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9][0-9], [2][0-9][0-9][0-9]//g'
```

Comment: he has tagged the question with `linux`

Comment: @Kent: My answer did include Linux part as well. Wouldn't it be better if an answer worked on other *nix versions as well?

Comment: and just curious, I have no experience with apple os. how many Mac user would install gnu stuff? in your opinion? >50%?

Comment: @Kent: This is just my personal opinion, majority of the Mac users don't use command line tools hence don't care of gnu or bsd :)

Comment: @kent: lol :) honestly I did not know OP was using Mac. Many thanks for the +1, I also up voted yours.